# Laravel using WHERE in eloquent ORM

Tags: php, laravel, orm, eloquent

I came across this

```
$user = User::whereConfirmationCode($confirmation_code)->first();
```

In Laravels eloquent ORM, can you append the tables row name in the where statment like above?

Before I saw this I would just written

eg: `$user = User::where('confirmation_code', '=', $confirmation_code)->first();`

Thanks

Answer (score 20, accepted):

'Yes, you can build dynamic where. 
It's parse in simple where statement.
Also you can build magic query like this:

```
$user = User::whereConfirmationCodeAndIdOrRole(12345, 5, 'admin')->first();
```

It will be transform to:

```
$user = User::where('confirmation_code', '=', 123456, 'and')->where('id', '=', 5, 'or')->where('role', '=', 'admin')->first();
```

Comment: TIL about dynamic where; I found the magic sauce in the files for the curious elves: Starts on line `2108` in file `\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder.php"`, which then calls the `dynamicWhere` function where unicorns and rainbows thrive

Comment: without having this in the docs how can one dream about using such syntax? my question is the same. how to explore more about this method? I wasted 3 hours just to find `whereConfirmationCode` method using "findinfiles"

Comment: you can dig into the source code, and investigate "magic" methods. This magic is done via __call methods. Laravel has lots of cool magic like this. I recommend investigating the source code.

Answer (score 2):

**I may be wrong. I was un-aware of magic query builder setup.**

That is a [custom query scope](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#query-scopes).

IE: A post model with a query scope to get all posts with 'status' = published.

```
class Post extends Eloquent {
    /**
     * Get all posts with 'status' published
     *
     * @param Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder $query
     * @return Builder $query
     */
     public function scopePublished(Builder $query)
     {
         return $query->where('status', 'published');
     }
}
```

Then using it:

```
 Post::published()->first();
```

Note parameters can be passed to the custom scope by passing them as parameters to the query scope after the query builder.

```
 public function scopeStatus(Builder $query, $status)
 {
     return $query->where('status', $status);
 }
```